# Problemas con el siguiente código

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando obtener un código con condicionales y comparativos que me permita crear un cuadro de diálogo y que me responda si está en mayúsculas, minúsculas o ambas. No identifico lo que me puede faltar para continuar.

```
const texto = prompt("Introducir Texto")
function info(texto) {
  alert(info) = prompt("Respuesta")
}
if (texto === texto.toUpperCase()) {
  resultado.push += "La frase está formada sólo por mayúsculas";
}
else if (texto === texto.toLowerCase()) {
  resultado.push += "La frase está formada sólo por minúsculas";
}
else {
  resultado.push += "La frase está formada por mayúsculas y minúsculas";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que estás intentando concatenar con `+=`, en vez de esto puedes **asignar** a la variable `resultado` el texto dependiendo a que condicional entre. Entonces, puedes inicializar un string para ver el resultado, así:

```js
const texto = prompt("Introducir Texto");
let resultado = "";

if (texto === texto.toUpperCase()) {
  resultado = "La frase está formada sólo por mayúsculas";
} else if (texto === texto.toLowerCase()) {
  resultado = "La frase está formada sólo por minúsculas";
} else {
  resultado = "La frase está formada por mayúsculas y minúsculas";
}

alert(resultado);
```

Además, recuerda que el método [**`push()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) es para **arrays**, no para **strings**.

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué es exactamente lo que te falla? No acabo de entender muy bien el código (más que nada porque sólo es un fragmento, en sí el condicional creo que es correcto) pero a priori lo primero que creo que puede ser un problema es el push. Si lo que quieres es concatenar un texto a *resultado*, lo que tienes que hacer es `resultado.push("texto a concatenar")` en vez de `resultado.push += "texto a concatenar"`, o, en su lugar, `resultado += "texto a concatenar"`

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con el siguiente código

en donde declaras una variable con el "resultado" esperado
después evalúas el texto y al final mandas un mensaje con la conclusión de tu evaluación.

```
const texto = prompt("Introducir Texto")
var resultado = "";
function info(texto) {
  alert(texto);
} 
if(texto === texto.toUpperCase()) {
  resultado = "La frase está formada sólo por mayúsculas";
  }
  else if(texto === texto.toLowerCase()) {
  resultado = "La frase está formada sólo por minúsculas";
  }
  else {
  resultado = "La frase está formada por mayúsculas y minúsculas";
  }
 info(resultado)
```

Comment: Gracias a todos. Muy buenas aportaciones.